# How to simulate Docker container losing internet connectivity?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, internet-connection

I'm using Docker Desktop for Windows, running a couple of linux containers using docker-compose.

These containers communicate with each other inside their own Docker network. One of the containers is set to push some data to the cloud.

I need some easy way to test the behavior of the cluster losing internet connectivity.

I do not want to disconnect my whole computer, just the Docker containers (without stopping them).

I tried restricting access of docker-compose in Windows Firewall, but that didn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Is there any Linux command I can run inside the running container to go offline?

**EDIT**

@vaibhand's answer disconnect a single container from the cluster network. Making it unreachable by other containers in the cluster. I need to disconnect the cluster from internet (simulating a real world internet connection outage), while keeping the internal cluster network alive so that they can still take to each other.

Comment: Supposing you use Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install net-tools` `sudo ifconfig down`

Comment: I'm using the Python docker official images. I don't think they have an ubuntu based one. They are mostly alpine or slim-buster.

Comment: Use "docker network ls" to list available networks 
and then docker network disconnect <NETWORK> <CONTAINER>

Comment: [Debian eth0](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ifupdown/ifup.8.en.html)

Comment: Ok, so I was able to install `net-tools` using the `3.9-buster` tag. But when I run `ifconfig down` (root access is disabled by the base image) I get `down: error fetching interface information: Device not found`. Any ideas?

Comment: @vaibhavnd This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Post it as an answer and I mark it :)

Comment: Why don't you block the resources (IPs) your applications connect to (I mean in Windows Firewall)? Don't block docker-compose. I believe docker-compose process itself does not attempt to go to outer Internet.

Answer (score 10):

Use `docker network ls` to list available networks
and then `docker network disconnect <NETWORK> <CONTAINER>`

Comment: I'm sorry but this disconnects the container from the network, making it unreachable by other containers in the cluster. I just need to disconnect from the internet while leaving the internal cluster network available for them to talk to each other.

Comment: theoretically, you can attach different containers to different docker network and to solve your problem one of them will not have connectivity to internet , see the steps here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720587/how-to-change-the-network-of-a-running-docker-container . .However unknown part for me is how to create a network which doesn't have connectivity to the internet .. this link may help https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: Thank you!
Just an update, to be able to attach the container back to the network you can use
`docker network connect <NETWORK> <CONTAINER>`